# How to set the checkbox value with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

I have parent element like:

```
<span style="background: yellow; padding: 50px;" onClick="setCheckBox()"><span>
<span> </span> <input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="100"></span></span>
```

and js function:

```
function setCheckBox() {
 document.getElementsByTagName('input'[0].checked = 'true';
}
```

Want to change the checkbox input on parent click (yellow color)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing a `)` after the tag name.

Comment: doesn't work after I add ")"

Answer (score 1):

you would use `.checked = true;` like so

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = true;
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="100">
```

Comment: Please check for dupes before posting an answer. Basic questions are always dupes, complex questions mostly are.

Comment: For some reason doesn't work for me

Comment: I put it inside the function and called the function on click

Comment: @ChrisG will do chief. 
use the id of your checkbox to find it

Comment: I edited function. @Mordor can you give me an example